# Cambiar el color del borde de un input mientras se escribe Angular [ngClass] - [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, input

¿Es posible cambiar el borde del input cuando se está escribiendo y mostrar el borde rojo si tiene un error o verde si es correcto?; teniendo en cuenta que estoy dentro del input ósea en focus del elemento html

**Html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<input type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="name" 
       [ngClass]="{'correct': name.length > 0,'error': name.length === 0}"
>
```

** Css **

```
.correct {
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

** Typescript **

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7an3od?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular agrega clases de estado como: `ng-invalid` y `ng-valid` a los `input`.

En tu caso puedes hacer esto:

Agregar en el archivo.css

```
/* remover el outline para que es ve el color del estado */
input:focus {
  outline: unset;
}
/* agregar borde rojo a los input que estén en estado inválido */
.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ng-valid{
  border:  1px solid green;
}
```

El en html agregar el atributo `required` al `input` para probar con esa validación:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hk7pva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[Referencia](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Si es solo en la pseudo-clase :focus, puedes hacer esto:

```
.correct:focus {
  outline: unset;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

.error:focus {
  outline: unset;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```